# how i can replace style with new one using jquery

Tags: jquery

i am inserting below css using jquery into head tag but problem is everytime i change the color using user interface it add another style tang and than css how can i remove already added and replace with new css please help.

```
<style charset="utf-8" type="text/css">div.contentMid2{background:#000;}div.module{background:#fff;}</style>
```

want to add couple of css on runtime but replacing with already added.

Answer (score 1):

if you need to change css values dynamically (`background-color:VARIABLE`), you can do one of this:

- with ajax you request a new stylesheet with new values. After that, you inject it into `head` tag.
- traverse all DOM every time you need to change something. `$('.someDIv').css()`. Be careful though, this way can be pretty resource eater :)

if you only need to add some static css, you can add/remove class from `body`:

```
$('body').addClass('new')
```

or

```
$('body').addClass('new2')
```

And from CSS:

```
.someClass {background:red}
body.new .someClass {background:blue}
body.new2 .someClass {background:green}
```

Comment: thanks lonut what i am doing is on changing event i am saving css properties to database using ajax but to change layout i am inserting newly change or new css to head section but it uplicates because layout hav 3,4 elements and on every elment change i am creating css how delete first thn add new:(

Comment: you don't need to delete. just add new stuff and the properties will be overwritten. Anyhow, on refresh, the extra code will be removed. so no ugly stuff will result :)

Comment: i think you can gave a NAME or ID to <style> tag and then change their attributes :)

Answer (score 0):

$('div.contentMid2').css({background:'#000'})

Comment: i guess he want to change ALL css from that page without traversing all dom :)